# How to get list element with minimal property?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-17

I write this code to find the youngest person:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class PersonImpl implements PersonInterface {

    @Override
    public Person youngest(List<Person> personList) {
        Integer minAge = personList.stream()
                .map(Person::getAge)
                .min(Comparator.comparing(Integer::valueOf))
                .orElse(null);
        return personList.stream()
                .filter(person -> person.getAge() == minAge)
                .toList()
                .stream()
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

As you can see I did it and is working correctly . Now I want to know if I can do this in a better way (maybe instead of having 2 "statements" to go done to only one?)
PS: I provided only the code since I assume that there is no need to post all the other classes in here just to review this one only.

Can someone explain me what can be done to have a better code(less lines)?
Thanks

Comment: @Birsan: I updated your question title to be more descriptive. Try to come up with a more descriptive tile in the future! :)

Comment: @user16320675: Yeah, maybe another title would be better. I think the new one is an improvement at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cut out the `map()` and have your comparator do the age lookup on `Person`:

```
return personList.stream()
        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge))
        .orElse(null);
```

If you know the list is non-empty, better to make that explicit by calling `get()` or `orElseThrow()` instead of `orElse()`. Or you can use the `Collections` helper instead of streams:

```
return Collections.min(personList, Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge));
```

By the way, calling `.toList().stream()` when you already have a stream is completely pointless. There's also no point in calling `Integer::valueOf` on an `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks for the point,  now I see where i start wrong .
Indeed that is pointless as you said , I will  look better  next time when I  will do something

Comment: All  those informations and the way you put it  it makes me undertand better :). Thank you once again O-)

Comment: @BirsanVictor: If you DON'T know that the argument list is non-empty, then it's probably better to use `Optional<Person>` as the return type of `youngest`!

Comment: To be more specific, instead of `Comparator.comparing(Integer::valueOf)` you could have used `Comparator.comparing(Function.identity())` or even `Comparator.naturalOrder()`. But in this specific case, you could have used `int minAge = personList.stream() .mapToInt(Person::getAge) .min() .orElse(-1);` That would also have solved the problem that it is not obvious to the reader whether the subsequent `person.getAge() == minAge` is correct. If `getAge()`’s return type is `Integer` (which we can’t know), this would be a reference comparison. With `int minAge`, it’s obviously a numeric comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `map` out the ages. It is not necessary to destruct just for finding the minimun value of an integer inside the struct.

```java
    return personList.stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.age))
            .orElse(null);
```